# com.android.volley.AuthFailureError using GET Method in -Android

Tags: android

I have a problem in my volley request. When I hit a url via postman then it shows response, but when I use volley then it shows **com.android.volley.AuthFailureError**.

```
private void loadURL() {
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://www.cricbuzz.com/match-api/22755/commentary.json", null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.v("javatoss", response.toString());

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.v("javatoss", error.toString());

                    Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                }
            }
    );
    // Adds the JSON object request "obreq" to the request queue
    requestQueue.add(obreq);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get response by using `com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2` library